# Is there any documentation on how to change the user interface of Potree?

Tags: lidar, references, gui, lastools, potree

Has anyone found or created any information regarding the different user interfaces of Potree?

I have created LiDAR portals using the LAStools [laspublish](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/laspublish_README.txt) tool to create Potree sites, but cannot see how I could adapt the GUI.

Here are two examples:

- http://potree.org/demo/potree_1.3/showcase/tern_auscover_chowilla.html
- http://potree.org/showcase/lion_head_simone_garagnani.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is from Potree 1.3, where all the available stuff fit into a [dat.gui panel](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) (top-right), whereas the second link is from Potree 1.5RC, where everything has been stacked into the sidebar to the left.

The sidebar could theoretically be modified by adjusting sidebar.html, sidebar.js and potree.css in the [src/viewer directory](https://github.com/potree/potree/tree/master/src/viewer).

You could also try to build a custom interface by not calling the viewer.loadGUI function and instead create your own html interface, similar to the stuff in sidebar.html, and then add actions to it similar to what's done in sidebar.js.

It's going to be a lot of work, though. The user interface with its tools and interaction with the 3D scene is one of the largest parts of the development.

If you just want to modify some settings, take a look at the available setters in viewer.js or simply open your browsers developer tools and type "viewer.set" and you should get a list of setter functions you can call.